# Tablet PC on Windows 8.1 with hdmi like a screen for raspberry

Tags: hdmi, screen, windows

I have a tablet PC Qumo vega 8008w and I want to use it like a screen for raspberry by using hdmi port, is it possible to do it without disassembling tablet PC only using hdmi port?

Comment: While your question isn't an exact duplicate of the one linked, the answer and reasons are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is almost certainly no. There are no small format tablets that I'm aware of that have ever been manufactured with an HDMI input. HDMI sockets on tablets are universally HDMI *outputs*, allowing you to display your tablet screen on something larger (TV, desktop monitor, projector, etc.). I can't read any of the documentation for this tablet as it's in Russian, but I would be *incredibly* surprised if the HDMI socket were an input.

You can control the Pi using the tablet over SSH (most commonly done using [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) on Windows), or you could experiment with a [VNC](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/) which will cast the Raspberry Pi desktop to the tablet.